# Vue Pinia vs Module

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pinia

I'd like to know the reasons to use Pinia over a javasript module with static members, I tried using both and I prefer the last one for this reasons:

- Pinia don't let you make private functions / state, unless you make a composition aproach that isn't documented, and involves returning manually functions/variables that you want to make public.
- With an abstract class with static members you know all the time which are public and which are private, the code looks cleaner,
- With Pinia you need to store the store in a variable in every template you use it like "let myStore = useMyStore()", instead with a module you can just access the property you need like "myModule.myProperty"

I know the pros of Pinia are the devtools plugin integration and also some extra functionality like $reset, and probably missing something, but still I dont find that enough so I'd like to know what do you think because it feels like there has to be something else that I'm missing. Thanks.

Comment: Just use underscore convention for private members, simple as that. From my experience, there's never a real necessity to physically enforce the capsulation, either at type or runtime level, it causes much more problems than solves. `myModule = useMyStore(); myModule.myProperty` requires extra line but allows to avoid some problems with circular dependencies. Vue supports classes for reactivity but there are several pitfalls associated with them. You'll have to write low-level code that uses reactivity api , while Pinia provides store options that don't require it.

Comment: @EstusFlask well I use refs in my module so I dont need to write any reactivity myself

Comment: This is what I called low-level. And you won't be able to use JS getters for reactivity, in case you use classes. I mean that it's unnecessary to explicitly use ref, reactive and computed with pinia store, https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/#option-stores . Also a significant thing you missed about the benefits of pinia is $patch, it's harder to implement yourself than $reset

Comment: Are you comparing Pinia to Vuex? If so, Pinia would be the way to go. No more mutations! Now, you can have a data store like `users = []` and have a `User` class which has all that model logic. 

Not sure if I'm addressing any of your concerns though. Having no mutations to deal with was enough to jump ship to Pinia.

Comment: no, I'm comparing pinia to a typescript class with static members, mutations was a self impossed limitation, and they realized wasn't good so they removed it, I'm not sure if you can call that an improvement.